# Datagrip automatically execute query from sql file when the file is changed

Tags: datagrip

Is there a way of making Datagrip automatically execute a query from sql file when the file is changed on disk? If yes, could you please describe the required steps in order to achieve such behavior?

Comment: There is no such feature available from the get-go. You could probably create a script though to execute via a filewatcher or something similar.

Feel free to create a new feature request and describe your use-case on YouTrack - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: Can we ask, what is the actual use-case here? Perhaps DataGrip can help some other way.